# getting basic hardware on Raspberry Pi working with ROS

Tags: raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have a ROS Groovy Galapagos bare bones installation from binary on the Raspberry Pi which has a Raspbian wheezy running on it. Please let know how to use it for some simple hardware like a switch and an LED connected to to the RPi. I would like the switch to switch on/off the LED through the ROS installation on the RPi.

Thanks in advance,
Praseen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65387/getting-basic-hardware-on-raspberry-pi-working-with-ros/) by [Praseen](https://answers.ros.org/users/5042/praseen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All,

I am currently working on the same thing and got at least the GPIOs working. SPI, I2C, RS232 is implemented but not tested yet. What you need is the bosch_drivers package
http://www.ros.org/wiki/bosch_drivers

Up to this point it only supports the Arduino and the Sub20 as hardware interface but I wrote a raspi_interface as well. You can get it from my private repo
https://github.com/kalectro/raspi_interface.git

As you can see it is still under heavy development but as I said the GPIOs should be working. I make use of the awesome wiringPi library which needs to be installed. Get it from here
http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/

Feel free to fork or submit issues if you find any bugs or have any suggestions

Kai

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0